# Send MediaStream through NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I have the **MediaStream** object returned from getUserMedia and can show it in my own screen.

The thing is, I don't know how to *send / pipe / stream/ * that MediaStream from Point A through NodeJS using socket.io to Point B.

My code right now is:

```
// Cámara
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {

    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream) || window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

    webcamstream = stream;                  

}, onVideoFail);
} else {
   alert ('failed');
}

});

function onVideoFail(e) {
    console.log('webcam fail!', e);
};
```

I need the way to make this stream being sent constantly to other user **using NodeJS**.

Answer (score 5):

- The comment made in the answer for [Audio and video conference with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583049) are still valid
- if you were to send the streams through socket.io instead of a peer connection, in any case that would be the raw video content (bytes). You would lose:

  - the streaming part (RTP/RTCP), and corresponding packet loss cancellation
  - the bandwidth adaptation
  - the encryption (DTLS)
  - the media engine (jitter correction, …)

  over webRTC.
- why not implement an SFU in node.js? Use node.js/socket.io for the signaling (i.e. the initial handshake) but also use node.js as a peer connection endpoint which relays/routes the media stream to (an)other(s) peer(s)? You would have an intermediate server like you seem to want, and all the advantages of webRTC.
- another solution is to use an MCU, google webrtc+mcu and you will find many.

Answer (score 1):

this might be a little late, but there's now a library called wrtc/node-webrtc. use that! https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc